# How to convert base64 into Blob in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am going to convert b64 to blob in react native.

But I am getting error on atob function.

Here are my codes.

```
var binary = atob(this.state.avatarSource.uri.split(',')[1]);
var byteNumbers = new Array(binary.length);

for(var i = 0; i < binary.length; i++) {
  byteNumbers.push(binary.charCodeAt(i));
}
var file = new Blob([new Uint8Array(byteNumbers)], {type: 'image/jpeg'});
```

Anybody has any idea?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I'm having the same problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a Blob from a base64 string in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245767/creating-a-blob-from-a-base64-string-in-javascript)

Comment: not duplicate, react native uses `JavascriptCore` which for instance doesn't implement `atob` and `btoa`

Answer (score 10):

Do not use `atob` or `btoa`, that only works in `Debug Mode`.

Because when you're using Debug Mode, you're running your JS code in browser (which should be V8), whereas if you're going to run the app in production mode it uses `JavascriptCore` which  does not have an `atob` or `btoa` implementation.

You can use [base-64](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/base64) to convert data to BASE64 encoded string, but I'm not sure if it can create a correct Blob object for you.

From my understanding, Blob is an bridge between JS context and file system, React Native does not have file system API itself yet, therefore you might get a Blob object but it's always empty.

If you're going to create an image from array contains numbers, you have a look at [react-native-fetch-blob](https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob) which is a project I'm working on, hopefully it can solve this kind of problems :)

Comment: Does react-native-fetch-blob provides Blob? im currently using "react-native-image-picker" which provides URI and base64. I need to convert it into blob. Please provide a suggestion.

Comment: react-native-fetch-blob solved this issue for me. Seems like it is a good solution if you have a base64 string you need to send to a http(s) post end point as it has built-in functionality for this conversion

Comment: 2021 here and react-native-fetch-blob, as well as the repository it further links to, are all unmaintained... there must be a way to convert a base64 to blob in 2021 right?

Comment: The solution I posted was the only one that didn't produce a corrupted file

Answer (score 6):

Ran into this situation where fetch() on Android will not work with a data URI. Instead, try the following:

```
import { Buffer } from "buffer";


const base64 = 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEU ....'
const buffer = Buffer.from(base64, "base64");

const blob = new Blob([buffer], { type: '[content-type]' })
```

content-type here would be 'image/png' if the base64 was a PNG file.

Answer (score 1):

right solution

1 = download this library  `npm i -S base-64`

2=   add this into import sction in your screen `import {decode as atob, encode as btoa} from 'base-64';`

3=  set this function in your screen

```
  const dataURLtoFile = (dataurl, filename) => {
var arr = dataurl.split(','),
  mime = arr[0].match(/:(.*?);/)[1],
  bstr = atob(arr[1]),
  n = bstr.length,
  u8arr = new Uint8Array(n);

while (n--) {
  u8arr[n] = bstr.charCodeAt(n);
}

return new File([u8arr], filename, {type: mime});
};
```

finally call this function

```
let file = dataURLtoFile(
                'data:image/png;base64,' + response.assets[0].base64, //if your bas64 include <data:image/png;base64,> rmove this from parameter 
                'test.png',
              );



console.log(file )
```

haaaa everything is ready

i hope this answer to help anyone

Answer (score 1):

Note that react native doesn't actually have Blobs - you can use the below code but note that the file will be loaded completely in memory so shouldn't be used for any large files. 'rn-fetch-blob' is the only library I have used that allows for native blobs - but it doesn't work with every package.

Note that the uri needs to be "file://path"

```
function uriToBlob(uri: string): Promise<Blob> {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
  xhr.responseType = 'blob'
  xhr.onload = () => {
    const blob = xhr.response
    resolve(blob)
  }
  xhr.onerror = (err) => {
    reject(err)
  }
  xhr.open('GET', uri)
  xhr.send()
})}
```

Update: This also works for me

```
 const res = await fetch(`file://${segment.uri}`) 
 const blobData = await res.blob()
```

Update 2:

```
  static async resolveBlob(b: Blob | PolyfillBlob): Promise<ResolvedBlob> {
const blobToResolve = b as any
const resolvedBlob = await new Promise<ResolvedBlob>((resolve) => {
  if (blobToResolve.created) {
    resolve(blobToResolve)
  }

  blobToResolve.onCreated(() => {
    resolve(blobToResolve)
  })
})

resolvedBlob.created = true

// TODO: We need this because of https://github.com/RonRadtke/react-native-blob-util/issues/241
if (resolvedBlob.size === undefined) {
  const blobPath = resolvedBlob.getReactNativeBlobUtilRef()
  const { size } = await ReactNativeBlobUtil.fs.stat(blobPath)
  resolvedBlob.size = size
}

return resolvedBlob
```

}

Comment: Hi `Sid`, does `const res = await fetch(`file://${segment.uri}`) ` work in React Native 0.70? Mine throws error of network request failed. I need convert a base64 image to blob before fetch PUT. Many thanks.

Comment: @user938363 i've updated my answer to show what I use

Answer (score 0):

Here is the conversion working on my RN 0.70.x:

```
import {decode, encode} from 'base-64';  //<<==yarn add base-64 if not available
// Convert base64 to blob 
    function base64ToUint8Array(base64) {
      try {      
        const binaryString = decode(base64); // Decode base64
        const len = binaryString.length;
        const bytes = new Uint8Array(len);
        for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
          bytes[i] = binaryString.charCodeAt(i);
        }
        return bytes;  //<<==blob
      } catch (err) {
        return null;
      };
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I am getting the base 64 of an image. After that I am displaying it from below code. Hope it may help you

```
let imgSrc = "data:image/png;base64," + base64ImageData;
<Image source={{uri: imgSrc, scale: 1}} style={{ height: 80, width: 80}}/>
```

Comment: Image is a specific comonent, how does it look in pure html?

Comment: @ThunD3eR This is React Native, there is no HTML

Answer (score -1):

you could try `fetch`

```
  let blob = await this.base64ToBlob(encoded);
  console.log('btoB64 resp === ', blob);

  async base64ToBlob(encoded) {
    let url = `data:image/jpg;base64,${encoded}`;
    let res = await fetch(url);
    let blob = await res?.blob();
    return blob;
  }
```

Comment: Fetch not working on android